# Lifecycle stores

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Are there stores for component lifecycle events? That is, instead of passing a function to e.g. onMount, can I instead `await onMount()`. `await tick()` seems to be the closest thing, but I was wondering if there's a store for the onMount event specifically or a way to create that store.

My usecase is Stripe Elements in Svelte.

Two asynchronous processes have to complete, and I can't guarantee which will happen first:

1. Stripe's js file has loaded (<svelte:head src=... on:load={render}>)
2. the component has rendered (onMount)

Rather than write code for both cases

```js
let event1Happened = false, event2Happened = false;
onEvent1(() => { event1Happened = true; if (event2Happened) { render() } });
onEvent2(() => { event2Happened = true; if (event1Happened) { render() } });
```

can I just write something like

`onEvent1(() => { await event2; render(); })`

or

`await event1; await event2; render();`?

or use an event modifier like

`<svelte:head src=... on:load|mounted={render}>`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a [reactive statement](https://svelte.dev/docs#3_$_marks_a_statement_as_reactive) for this logic.

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    let mounted = false;
    let scriptLoaded = false;
    
    onMount(() => { mounted = true; })
    // simulate a script load
    setTimeout(() => { scriptLoaded = true }, 500);
    
    // this block will run when mounted or scriptLoaded changes
    $: if (mounted && scriptLoaded) {
        render();
    }
    
    function render() {
        console.log('rendered');
    }
</script>

<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```